# url rewriting conflict with cloudflare SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /dl.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This rule stopped working after switching to https / SSL with Cloudflare and i can't figure why ?

If i try the exact same URL's without the https:// part, the pages are accessibles, so the rule is working but only for non-secured URL's

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the http and the https variants of a domain are served by two completely separate hosts from the point of view of the http server. That means you have separate configurations. Most likely the ssl host does *not* have enabled the interpretation of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Take a look at the apache [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive...

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: i don't have access to configuration files, is there a way to toggle AllowOverride All through .htaccess file ? it's for a private admin section so i'm not too worried about the performance hit however it's a really good information as i am using lots of .htaccess on others live websites and i didn't know it could slow the server so thanks for letting me know

Comment: nevermind, i just realised this isn't a htaccess problem as static files are also returning 404 errors, my bad... Cloudflare SSL doesnt seems to like my ISPConfig server :(

Comment: @comdex There is no way to enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files in those files themselves... Think about what you ask ;-)

Comment: If even requests to static files result in a http status 404 then chances are that the hosts `DocumentRoot` settings simply differ.